# Rotate box in Forest

Tags: forest

i am making a binary tree with forest. I am new to the drawing things in Latex.

This is my code:

```
\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, fill=white!20, text width=1.6cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm},
      line/.style={draw, very thick, color=black!80, -Stealth},
    }

\begin{forest}
  arrow to/.style n args=2{%
    delay={%
      tikz+={%
        \draw [every edge, line] () -- (!#1) node [above, midway] {#2};
      },
    },
    !u.s sep+=30pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={%
        node [left,pos=.75, anchor=mid east] {#1}
      },
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={%
        node [right,pos=.75, anchor=mid west] {#1}
      },
    },
  },
  for tree={%
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=south,
    block,
    edge={line},
    l sep+=10pt,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  forked edges,
    [Fehler Injektion
      [Hardware
        [Kontaktlose Injektion
          [Laser
          ]
          [Strahlungs basiert
            [Heavy-Ion
            ]
            [Neutron
            ]
            [EMI
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [Kontakt Injektion
          [Active Probing
          ]
          [Pin Level
          ]
          [TAP
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Software
        [Kompilier zeit
        ]
        [Laufzeit
        ]
      ]
      [Emulation
        [FPGA 
        ]
        [LLVM
        ]
      ]
      [Simulation
        [VHDL
        ]
      ]
   ]
\end{forest}
```

My question is: Can i rotate single boxes and how does it work?

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

- please always provide complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. it is not fun to guessing, what document class you use, whats looks your page layout and which packages and libraries are needed to compile your code fragment ...
- for rotate nodes just use `rotate=90` in nodes where is needed
- code for your tree can be more concise and with better placement of nodes, but temporary i haven't time to do this (also this is not a question)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, fill=white!20, text width=1.6cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm},
      line/.style={draw, very thick, color=black!80, -Stealth},
    }

\begin{forest}
  arrow to/.style n args=2{%
    delay={%
      tikz+={%
        \draw [every edge, line] () -- (!#1) node [above, midway] {#2};
      },
    },
    !u.s sep+=30pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={%
        node [left,pos=.75, anchor=mid east] {#1}
      },
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={%
        node [right,pos=.75, anchor=mid west] {#1}
      },
    },
  },
  for tree={%
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    anchor=south,
    block,
    edge={line},
    l sep+=10pt,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  forked edges,
    [Fehler Injektion
      [Hardware
        [Kontaktlose Injektion
          [Laser
          ]
          [Strahlungs basiert
            [Heavy-Ion,rotate=90
            ]
            [Neutron,rotate=90
            ]
            [EMI,rotate=90
            ]
          ]
        ]
        [Kontakt Injektion
          [Active Probing,rotate=90
          ]
          [Pin Level,rotate=90
          ]
          [TAP,rotate=90
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Software
        [Kompilier zeit,rotate=90
        ]
        [Laufzeit,rotate=90
        ]
      ]
      [Emulation
        [FPGA,rotate=90
        ]
        [LLVM,rotate=90
        ]
      ]
      [Simulation
        [VHDL
        ]
      ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```